# While ffmpeg is recording, I want it to create a smaller and lower quality video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-compression

Currently I am using this...

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 1 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -t 00:00:10 Output.mkv
```

While ffmpeg is recording a video, I want it to significantly reduce both the **size** and **quality** compared to the ffmpeg command above.

In case you are curious, I am recording brief quality assurance videos to ensure a simple little web scraper I wrote in Python is scraping data properly (specifically, that it is clicking on a particular button, at a particular time, on a particular web page). My Python script triggers the command above to start recording my screen a few seconds before my Python script is supposed to click on that button.

Of course, to verify a button on a web page had been clicked on, low quality video resolution would normally suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For libx264/libx265 the most important option to reduce both the size and quality is `-crf`. This option controls quality. A value of 51 provides the worst quality. If it's too terrible then use a lower number.

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 1 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f pulse -channels 2 -i default -t 00:00:10 -c:v libx264 -crf 51 -c:a libopus Output.mkv
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: Thank you! Actually `crf 51` is not too terrible for my needs. Sure. It is ugly. Of course it is. But it suffices for my current need.

Comment: Thank you! Actually `crf 51` is not too terrible for my needs. Sure. It is ugly. Of course it is. But it suffices for my current need.

Answer (score 0):

For significantly reduce both the size and quality  of **Output.mkv** you can use the next ffmpeg configuration:

**crop**: iw-(cut width in pixels):ih-(cut heigth in pixels)

**scale**: to set the ratio and resolution (example 1700x800)

**crf**: to set quality, where 0 is lossless, 23 is default, and 51 is worst possible. A lower value is a higher quality and a subjectively sane range is 18-28. Consider 18 to be visually lossless

**bitrate value**:   -b:v *value* -minrate *value*  and -maxrate  max *value* (example -b:v 4000K -minrate 2000K -maxrate  6000K)

**preset**: in theory slow is best quality/size, and you can probe ultrafast
*superfast
veryfast
faster
fast
medium – default preset
slow
slower
veryslow*

Cut a part of video, changue the resolution, changue crf, and bitrate, first only video, then you can add audio in other work, dont mix, repeat, is very important, encoding/decoding audio and video separate, then you can mix all, but first the video like in this example

```
ffmpeg -i  Output.mkv   -map 0:v  -vf  crop=iw-150:ih-85,scale=ih*16/9:ih,scale=1072:732,setsar=1   -c:v libx264 -crf 17  -b:v 4000K -maxrate  6000K -bufsize 4M   -movflags -faststart  -preset veryfast -dn video-new.mkv
```

Comment: Thank you! That is an illuminating list of information.